# Can't logout from Stack Exchange

Tags: support, bug, login

I am unable to log out from Stack Exchange in my browser, in both PC and mobile. After logging out, when I open the site again it appears as I am already logged in. I have not enabled the remembering of my password for this site, either.

Comment: Why oh why would you want to log out anyway? : P

Comment: Click on the small triple horizontal bar icon on the top right (extreme right) of your screen when you open physics stack exchange. A drop down list appears. Click "log out".

Comment: @Blue - That's a meaningful suggestion, but I think, the OP wrote "_After logging out_ ...", so presumably he/she knows about that icon. I think, what the OP means is, hitting log out there isn't working for him/her. Perhaps that's why the OP tagged this with a "bug". :)

Comment: Once i have logged in i must clear cache /history to log out...

Comment: Probably your browser stores the password and keeps you logged in

Comment: SE does some slightly complex things to enable automatic network-wide login, so I'd definitely recommend searching on [meta.SE]. There should be some information there about it.